# Returning responses from got (requests) to an object for callback

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, post, lambda, request

I am using got module to make POST requests to get data.
I am wanting to synchronously call 3 APIs, get the response objects, then callback. I am having trouble getting returning the response to callback object. It is returning {} instead of the actual response. I would also like to make all of these calls synchronously so that the requests are occurring simultaneously to save time.

```js
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    
    async function getDATA1() {
     return await got.post('https://url.com/serviceapi/1/', {
         responseType: 'json',
            resolveBodyOnly: true,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
      json: {
                "Input": {
                    "item":1,
                }
            }
     }).json();
    }

    async function getDATA2() {
     return await got.post('https://url.com/serviceapi/2/', {
         responseType: 'json',
            resolveBodyOnly: true,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
      json: {
                "Input": {
                    "item":2,
                    "color":"blue",
                }
            }
     }).json();
    }

    async function getDATA3() {
     return await got.post('https://url.com/serviceapi/3/', {
         responseType: 'json',
            resolveBodyOnly: true,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
      json: {
                "Input": {
                    "item":3,
                    "size":"large",
                }
            }
     }).json();
    }
    
    callback(null,{
        "DATA1": getDATA1(),
        "DATA2": getDATA2(),
        "DATA3": getDATA3(),
    });
};
```

The response I am getting is

```js
{
  "DATA1": {},
  "DATA2": {},
  "DATA3": {}
}
```

The response I am expected/ want is something like this

```js
{
  "DATA1": {
               "available_f":"Y"
           },
  "DATA2": {
               "available_f":"N"
           },
  "DATA3": {
               "available_f":"Y"
           },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those async functions will need to be awaited so you would need to do something like this that will wait till all of the requests have resolved and then you can gather the results and return them through the callback.

```js
const got = require('got');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

    async function getDATA1() {
        return await got.post('https://url.com/serviceapi/1/', {
            responseType: 'json',
            resolveBodyOnly: true,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            json: {
                "Input": {
                    "item": 1,
                }
            }
        }).json();
    }

    async function getDATA2() {
        return await got.post('https://url.com/serviceapi/2/', {
            responseType: 'json',
            resolveBodyOnly: true,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            json: {
                "Input": {
                    "item": 2,
                    "color": "blue",
                }
            }
        }).json();
    }

    async function getDATA3() {
        return await got.post('https://url.com/serviceapi/3/', {
            responseType: 'json',
            resolveBodyOnly: true,
            username: 'user',
            password: 'pass',
            json: {
                "Input": {
                    "item": 3,
                    "size": "large",
                }
            }
        }).json();
    }

    Promise.all([getDATA1, getDATA2, getDATA3]).then(values => {
        return callback(null, {
            DATA1: values[0],
            DATA2: values[1],
            DATA3: values[2]
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        return callback(err);
    });
};
```